# How to MOVE or MERGE different fields into the subfile in ONE LINE in RPGLE

Tags: move, rpgle, rpg

i'm stuck on how to move or display different value from different field in one line.

My output supposed to look like this

[Real Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6vtB.png)

but for now, my output is look like this

[Recent Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjfcX.png)

This is my physical file

[CUREXG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzB43.png)

I have three field in physical file which are :

- EXGDAT = date And the key field
- EXGCOD = exchange code
- EXGRAT = exchange rate

I have 2 dates, and basically i need the output to only have 2 line which one is 31 May, and the second one is 1 june.
I tried to group them by doing the if condition but it didnt work. How I'm supposed to do? Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Add a logical for the table by date, exchange code
fcurexg2   if   e           k disk   

**---------------------- start of your code
*LOVAL setll curexg
       read curexg
       dou  %eof(curexg);

c       eval @@date =  exgdat
c       exsr $GetVals         

        eval rrn = rrn + 1
        write sfl01

   // move to the next date
exgdat  setgt curexg
        read curexg
        enddo

**------------------------
Begsr  $GetVals;  // runs for each code -- usd, eur, etc
  @@gcod = 'USD'
  exsr $GetGrat;
  move   @@grat   USD

  @@gcod = 'GBP'
  exsr $GetGrat;
  move   @@grat   GBP

  @@gcod = 'EUR'
  exsr $GetGrat;
  move   @@grat   EUR

  @@gcod = 'AUD'
  exsr $GetGrat;
  move   @@grat   AUD

  @@gcod = 'SGD'
  exsr $GetGrat;
  move   @@grat   SGD

Endsr;
**------------------------
Begsr $GetGrat;  //find the rate for that date and code
*like  define curexg   @@date
*like  define exgcod   @@gcod
*like  define exgrat   @@grat


  clear @@grat
  Chain (@@date: @@gcod) curexg2;  //the new logical 
  if %found(curexg2);
    @@grat = exgrat
  endif
Endsr;
**------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will try to do your code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi sir, I already try your coding, but got some error which the key field in chain is greater than key field in file.  What should I do?

Comment: Sure.  In debug, what were the values of the variables used in the chain?

Answer (score 0):

consider an SQL function. Here is an SQL function which returns the exchange rate of a specific exchange code and date.

```
CREATE or replace function curexg_exchangeRate(
inDate       date,                             
inCurrency   char(3))                          
returns      decimal(7,2)                      
language sql                                   
                                               
begin                                          
                                               
declare      Sqlcode int ;                     
declare      vSqlcode DECIMAL(5,0) default 0 ; 
declare      vExgrat decimal(7,2) default 0 ;  
                                               
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION      
SET  vSqlcode = SQLCODE ;                      
                                               
select       a.exgrat                          
into         vExgrat                           
from         curexg a                          
where        a.exgdat <= inDate                
             and a.exgcod = inCurrency         
order by     a.exgdat desc                     
fetch first row only ;
 
return       coalesce( vExgrat, 0 ) ;
end
```

RPG code that calls the exchangeRate sql function:

```
d usdRate         s              7p 2                                  
d gbpRate         s              7p 2                                  
d eurRate         s              7p 2                                  
 /free                                                                 
  // get exchange rate, of each exchange code, as of the specified date
      exec sql                                                         
      set         :usdRate =  curexg_exchangeRate( :exgdat, 'USD' ) ;  
      exec sql                                                         
      set         :gbpRate =  curexg_exchangeRate( :exgdat, 'GBP' ) ;  
      exec sql                                                         
      set         :eurRate =  curexg_exchangeRate( :exgdat, 'EUR' ) ;
```

this code reads the exchange rates for each exchange date:

```
  // list exchange rates for each exchange date.                       
      exec sql                                                         
      declare c1 cursor for                                            
      with t1 as (                                                     
      select distinct  a.exgdat                                        
      from             curexg a                                        
      order by         a.exgdat )    
      select      a.exgdat,                                       
                  curexg_exchangeRate( a.exgdat, 'USD' ) usdRate, 
                  curexg_exchangeRate( a.exgdat, 'GBP' ) gbpRate, 
                  curexg_exchangeRate( a.exgdat, 'EUR' ) eurRate  
      from        t1 a                                            
      order by    a.exgdat ;                                      
                                                                  
      exec sql                                                    
      open        c1 ;                                            
                                                                  
      exec sql                                                    
      fetch       c1                                              
      into        :exgdat, :usdRate, :gbpRate, :eurRate ;         
      if          sqlcode <> 0 ;                                  
      leave ;                                                     
      endif ;                                                     
                                                                  
  // write to subfile                                             
      sfExgdat    = exgdat ;                                      
      sfUsdRate   = usdRate ;                                     
      sfGbpRate   = gbpRate ;                                     
      sfEurRate   = eurRate ;  
      write       sflrcd ; 
                           
      enddo ;              
                           
      exec sql             
      close       c1 ;     
                           
      *inlr       = '1' ;  
      return ;             
 /end-free
```